App store connect: share introductory offer among 2 subscription groups
I have two subscription groups (Small Package, Large Package) each with two subscriptions (Monthly, Annual).
I want to offer two months free to each new user (i.e. a user that never had ANY Subscription). Do you know if/how can I do that?
Options considered up to now that are not working:

duplicate each subscription (i.e. monthly, monthly_freetier, annual, annual_freetier). However, even if in my application I display either only the freetier or only the other ones, the user sees all 4 in the apple store
Set up an Introductory offer on every subscription (works as desired within the same group, but not across different groups)

Do you have any suggestion? PS. I am using revenuecat to retrieve the user purchase history.
